# How to setup celery worker to log all task function calls to one file

Tags: python, django, logging, celery, django-celery

I have Django application with such logging configuration.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(filename)s:%(lineno)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'cron': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'cron.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'admin': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'admin.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'app': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'app.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'core': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'app.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'metrics': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'metrics.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
        'pixel': {
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'pixel.log',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'cron_api': {
            'handlers': ['cron'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'main': {
            'handlers': ['app'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'admin': {
            'handlers': ['admin'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'spa_api': {
            'handlers': ['app'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'metrics': {
            'handlers': ['metrics'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'pixel': {
            'handlers': ['pixel'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    },
}
```

Also I have a celery worker. I want to log every activity that happens inside the task to celery_worker.log, even if task calls a function from main or cron_api application.

For example:
If `main.celery_tasks.task1.task1` calls `main.service.google.get_campaign`, I want all logs from `get_campaign` to be in worker.log. Also I want no logs related to this task to be in app.log.

How to achieve this?
P.S.: Also I'd like to have a scalable solution. If number of worker increases - I'd like each worker to write all logs related to task call to it's file.

Comment: If you're setting up logging in each file, but you want to override those when the task queue calls them, you either need to patch the logger (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) or pass around the logger you want to use. Patching isn't ideal since it isn't thread safe (a non-task call to `get_campaign` will be logged in worker.log if a worker is currently calling that function in another thread)

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way except those two? Both sound not so great)

Comment: If you encapsulate the functions in a class, you can have the class accept a logger during instantiation. By default, the class can use the logger defined in that file (which looks like it would be "main" or "app.log").

Comment: I don't like rerouting the logs for the obvious reason that it makes finding all of the logs for a particular function/module harder. If you want to be able to trace the worker, I believe you can include the thread in the log output. You could match the thread identifier and timestamps to determine when something is being ran by a worker.

Comment: Thank you! I'll consider that!